# Is there a fancy and short solution for using the null coalescing operator with constants in PHP?

Tags: php, constants, conditional-operator, null-coalescing-operator

Since [PHP 8](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php#refsect1-function.constant-changelog) the `constant()` function throws an error instead of returning `null` and generating an `E_WARNING` when the given constant is not defined, and therefore I can't use the following code to **set a variable** anymore:

```
$foo = $SESSION['bar'] ?? constant("MY_CONSTANT") ?? "baz";
```

My obvious quick solution for this is changing that line to:

```
$foo = $SESSION['bar'] ?? (defined("MY_CONSTANT") ? constant("MY_CONSTANT") : "baz");
```

It honestly bothers me a little because I like how the first code is cleaner and do not force me to write **ugly giant ternary sequences with a billion parentheses** in case I want to add more constants to that `??` cascade. I also tried - hopeless because the (short) documentation around the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) already stated that `??` was just a shortcut for `isset()` in a ternary - the following:

```
$foo = $SESSION['bar'] ?? MY_CONSTANT ?? "baz";
```

But it didn't work - as expected. Another solution would be creating a function that returns `null` when the constant is not defined, such as:

```
function defined_constant($constant) {

    return (defined($constant) ? constant($constant) : null);

}

$foo = $SESSION['bar'] ?? defined_constant("MY_CONSTANT") ?? "baz";
```

I would like to know if there's any solution **without creating new functions or changing the `php.ini` file** that would allow me use only `??`s as in that first line of code.

It is ok if the answer to my question is just a "no, there is no solution", but I'm intrigued and I can't find much stuff about this on the internet. PHP also seems to have just a few native functions around constants (three [miscellaneous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.misc.php) and the `get_defined_constants()`?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

true way is detect all undefined constants and define: `defined('MY_CONSTANT') || define('MY_CONSTANT', 'baz');` and etc.

if you want save this trash constructions, then you can use something like this `get_defined_constants()['MY_CONSTANT'] ?? 'baz'`

Comment: I think it's a very insteresting solution and I even decided to test (for curiosity) how slower would it be to call `get_defined_constants()` for this. It is about _~40-60%_ slower compared to the "ternary with uggly parentheses" method and to the `defined_constant()` function method if you have 10 simple `int` constants defined (and its slowniness raises about _~0.5-2%_ for each other 10), but since its **less than a ten thousandth of a second matter** I think it's absolutely ok to use this method sporadically for simple operations (which was my question goals). Thanks!!